# Why does the Visual Studio 16.9 Toolbar flake when migrating a solution from .Net 3 to 5?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I ask the question so I can leave at least one answer as to why this happens, and perhaps alleviate someone else's pain. (I suspect there are other reasons and other solutions, please feel free ...)

I updated Visual Studio from 16.8 to 16.9 to facilitate migrating a .NET Core 3.1 solution to .NET 5

It had an ASP.NET Core Web API project, as well as several other executable projects (WPF fks).

Upon migrating the project, the icons for the projects changed(??), and a very useful dropdown from the toolbar went missing, THE ONE THAT ALLOWS YOU TO SELECT WHICH PROJECT IS DEFAULT STARTUP

[image: VisualStudioWithOutProjectChooser]

vs.

[image: VisualStudioWithProjectChooser]

How do you google this? (its called "startup projects" in the standard toolbar)

Ok, well I found the line that got mangled.

When Visual Studio finds a Web API project it assumes this is the top priority and that you will be launching it with IIS and thus hides the project select dropdown, UNLESS you add an override line to the launchSettings.json which says "launchBrowser": false, which of course I had set long ago, because I just run it as a service with Kestrel.

The migration from .NET 3.1 to .NET 5 removed this line(?) and boom, Super Handy drop to choose the default project disappears.

Hope this helps someone.

Oh, and it is hard to debug, because the setting gets copied to the .vs folder (the hidden settings visual studio is holding for your project), and it sticks in weird ways, and of course isn't there when you pull from svn, etc...

So, I had to change the launchSettings.json file, then REMOVE the Web project, then Add the project again. (And even then things were weird until I restarted Visual Studio). Cross my fingers and hope it sticks.

Answer (score 0):

More info:
changing the project names also lost the dropdown. whatever this setting is, its buried in the secret .vs[SolutionName]\v16.suo file

Saw somewhere else: Build the Debug, then Build the Release for each project in the solution, then unload one of those projects, then load the project again. Worked.

A detail that might be important is that my solution has a WebAPI project in the solution.